# Telerik DataGrid versus DynamicData

Tags: dynamic-data, telerik-grid

I have a good 'ol ASP.NET Winforms grid requirement where an admin user needs to CRUD products, orders and other data in a shopping site.

So I need to be able to:

- Display a table of data (use joins across SQL tables)
- Filter through order fields
- View paging
- In some of the tables, edit data, validate it, add a row

And this can be done through both DynamicData and the Telerik DataGrid as well as a number of other ASP.NET Winform Grids.

Is there any reason the third party controls are necessary given DynamicData performs all these operations? Development speed is an issue for us, and if the third party control are quicker to use and extend, this would be a benefit for us.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dynamic Data ll the time and you don't need anything else howeve eI do use a version of the Telerik RadGrid in Dynamic Data. I like to use DD becuase I am able to keep the really clean by driving it via metadata.